# Three.js cannot recognize OBJ format files exported with NURBS?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, html5-canvas

Obj files exported by rhino software，How to Convert Mesh Surface into Surface in three.js 
[image]

I tried flatShading and smoothShading, but it didn't work.

The following figure is the vertex normal
[image]
The following is a reflection map added.
[image]

```
        var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        objLoader.setPath('models/obj/');
        objLoader.load('ball2.obj', function (object) {
            var materials = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                color: 0xF3FFE2,
                specular: 0xffffff,
                // shininess: 2,
                // shading:THREE.SmoothShading
                // flatShading: true
                // smoothShading:true,
                envMap: scene.background
            });
            object.children.forEach(function (child) {
                        child.material = materials;
                        child.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
                        child.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
                    });
            object.scale.set(15, 15, 15);
            scene.add(object);
        });
```

my modul https://gist.github.com/grayFinger/308a07877d3deb10ad0694f1ffa3c383

Please answer for me.What The effect I want is
[image].

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You will have to show your code (and your obj file) so your problem can be reproduced.

Comment: ok，It has been added. Thank you.

Comment: Your model renders correctly in https://threejs.org/editor/. Unfortunately, I am unable to understand your question. Maybe someone else can...

Comment: @WestLangley Thank you for your reply. I have added my question.

Comment: Try not computing new normals. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29202480/three-js-calculating-vertex-normals/29221549#29221549. Also, use the current revision of three.js -- including the loaders.

Comment: My problem has been solved.thank you very much.you are my hero！:)